# if arrays are stored on heap, then why does their size not change on resizing them with temporary array

Tags: java, arrays

I know that `arrays` are stored on heap. If we pass them in any method and modify any index value, then it will be reflected outside that method also.

But why doesn't this apply with resizing their capacity. Say, if I pass original array and temporary array (with increased capacity) as argument in some method. Inside that method I copy the original array content in given temporary array and assign that temp array to original array, then why is it that outside that method, it shows same old size to original array. May be I can explain it with below code

**code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {4,7,3,1,5,8,2,8};
        System.out.println("before "+arr.length);
        int[] temp = new int[arr.length*2];
        resizeArray(arr,temp);
        System.out.println("after "+arr.length);
        
    }

    
private static void resizeArray(int[] arr,int[] temp) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        arr = temp;
        System.out.println("inside "+arr.length);
    }
```

I was expecting the output as **after 16**
But it printed **after 8**

I know if I had returned `arr` then it would come out to be of size 16. But why is it that. We can change any of index's element value from any method.. But not its original size. Confused.

Comment: It’s because you pass a reference to the array into your method. Inside the method you overwrite the reference with the reference to temp (arr=temp). The outside code still has got the old reference  to arr and is not aware, what happens inside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, when you pass an array to a method, you're providing a reference to the array, not the array itself. Consequently, any alterations made to the elements of the array within the method will reflect outside the method because both the original array and the method's copy point to the same memory location.

However, when you modify the reference itself (for instance, by assigning a new array to the reference), it doesn't affect the original reference outside the method. In your resizeArray method, when you reassign arr to temp, you're only altering the local copy of the reference arr, which doesn't propagate outside the method.

To achieve the desired outcome, you can have the resizeArray method return the resized array and then assign it back to the original array reference in the main method. This way, the reference in the main method will point to the resized array, resulting in the expected output of after 16.

Answer (score 1):

Your arr variable is on the stack memory. Arr itself is on heap memory. What you did is just changing local variable "arr". Nothing much. Local variables and parameter variables created on the stack.

What created on heap is

```
new int[arr.length * 2];
```

```
int[] arr;
```

arr is on the stack. You did not create any object on heap. arr is like pointer in C.

```
new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}; // expression evaluates some address on heap
```